# kendo Grid custom edit send [object Object]

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, editor

I want implement kendo Grid custom editor (dropdownlist).

everythin is ok but if create new record or update exists record when dropdown column is null I got error in updating, in debugging I saw 
'[object Object]' sent as value of continent column , 
but when dropdown column has value I can change dropdown value and update record is OK!!!

my code is:

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8090/hr";

var countryDataSource = 
        new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {
                                        models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                                    };
                                }
                            },
                            read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/countries",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/countries/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/countries/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/countries/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                }
                },
                schema   : {
                    data  : "items"
                    },
                model: {id : "CD_CONT",
                        fields: { 
                           CD_CONT : { type: "string",editable : false}, 
                           NAME_CONT : { type: "string",editable : true,nullable : false}, 
                           CONTINENT : { type: "string",editable : true,nullable : true}
                        }
                    }
            });


var continentDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [ { continent:"1",name:"asia"},
            { continent:"2",name:"europ"},
            { continent:"3",name:"america"}
          ]
});

$('#grid).kendoGrid({
            toolbar: ["create","save", "cancel",],
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "CD_CONT" ,
                    title: "Cd cont"  
                },
                {
                    field: "NAME_CONT" ,
                    title: "Name cont" 
                },
                {
                    field: "CONTINENT" ,
                    title: "Continent",
                    editor: function ContinentDropDown(container, options) {
                                        $('<input data-text-field="name" data-value-field="continent" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                                            .appendTo(container)
                                            .kendoDropDownList({
                                                dataSource: continentDataSource,
                                                dataTextField: "name",
                                                dataValueField: "continent"
                                            });
                                    }
                }
                ],
            dataSource: countryDataSource ,
            editable: "inline"
        });
```

also how to set field template to show textValue of Continent in grid?

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to add the `name` in your editor?

```
$('<input data-text-field="name" data-value-field="continent" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" name='" + options.field + "'/>')
```